# Using Python with venv and PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-venv

I'd prefer to use the canonical 'venv' when using Pycharm. Pycharm doesn't seem to support venv (it supports virtualenv and others).
What do I need to do to safely use venv?

Comment: create environment using venv and add the python interpreter to the path in pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use venv, then in Pycharm Ctrl-Alt-S, Project -> Project Interpreter -> Viretualenv Environment -> Existing environment -> Interpreter (set path from your venv here). All seems to work

Comment: OK. Will it handle package management, such as requirements.txt in the project home directory, as usual?

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook Yes, it does. You can manage packages in the virtual environment via mentioned Project Interpreter setting, and will get some tips/functions when open requirements.txt